# Edittext content is not refreshed if I change it

Tags: android, sql, database, android-edittext

I asked this question yesterday, but I wrote it far more complicated than I think this problem is. I am very confused and I found some very similar questions here, but neither of them solved my problem. So I have a listview, every listview contains an image, a textview and an edittext, but only the edittext is important.
If I click on the textview, I want to log the content of it for testing. My problem is if the user changes it then after the change I log the same thing. So changing it in the emulator and not using setText, it does nothing. I have a database, in every of the listview there is an edittext (holder.quant).

class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {

```
    LayoutInflater inflat;
    ViewHolder holder;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<EachRow> objects) 
    {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        inflat=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflat.inflate(R.layout.row_checkox, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView111);
            holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView111);



            holder.quant = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);


            holder.image.setOnClickListener(CustomList.this);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


          @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 TextView tv = (TextView) v ;
            String text_of_clicked_textview = tv.getText().toString();

             final String[] ddata = text_of_clicked_textview.split(" "); //split the result using the spaces (so you could obtain the name, hotness and the other string you use)


                final long yy = Long.parseLong(ddata[0]);



                info.open();
                info.updateQuan(yy, holder.quant.getText().toString());
                Log.i("tagitagi", holder.quant.getText().toString());
                info.close();
            }
        });



        EachRow row= getItem(position);
        EachRow row2= getItem2(position);
        holder.quant.setText(row2.text);

        holder.textView.setText(row.text);
        NullPointerException
        holder.image.setTag(position);
        holder.quant.setTag(position);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public EachRow getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }
    public EachRow getItem2(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list2.get(position);
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView image;
        EditText quant;


    }
}

private class EachRow
{
    String text;
    boolean checkBool;
}
```

I tried addTextChangedListener, but it gives me an error when I use settext. So what is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out how can I make it work. The holder.quant.gettext().toString does not work, even if I click on the textview of one of the rows I cannot log the content of the textview. The holder somehow blocks it, I will always log the same textview...

So I needed to create a new method:

```
public String getTextOfSelectedRow(int position) {
                       return list.get(position).text;
        }
```

The list contains the rows, the .text comes from the method:

```
private class EachRow
    {
        String text;
        boolean checkBool;
    }
```

and the definition of the holder:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView=inflat.inflate(R.layout.row_checkox, null);
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView111);
                holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView111);

                holder.quant = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
           holder.button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialogQuan);
                holder.image.setOnClickListener(CustomList.this);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



            holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {....
```

So after this the onClick method:

```
kmultip = getTextOfSelectedRow(position).toString();
```

So with this I can refer to the holder.quant or holder.textview or anything that is in a row. I still do not know why the simple holder.quant.getText().toString does not work, but with this, so refering to the position of a row will makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight. If you click on the TextView, you want to log the content of the EditText?

Why not in the onClick method of the listener on the TextView just call:

```
Log.d("EditText Content", holder.quant.getText().toString() );
```

You do not need an OnTextChangeListener for simply grabbing the content in the editText.

Comment: Ajcodez, this is what is happening here, i dont understand you. it is in the last row

Comment: the problem is when i modify the content in the emulator and log it i get the same data

Comment: Ah when you change the text in the EditText and click to log it, you get the same result. Perhaps there is a problem with your holder?

Comment: yes, i get the same result. i think my holder is okay. should'nt i set the text somehow else?

Comment: I tried in a new android project without the holder thing. It really works. I refresh the code in the frist post with the whole myAdapter class.

Answer (score 0):

first - You are filling the view with content only if it is a new view. This works only if you'll have all the list content static. Are you sure?

second - you are not using the functionality of the ArrayAdapter. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9532548/715269)